# Shiny server is throwing "Couldn't normalize path" of package i18n-1.2.0

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

As the title suggest I've been unable to use my Rmarkdowns in Shiny Server on a Ubuntu machine due to this little error. However I haven't been able to reproduce it in my machine which suggests that the problem is either on the R installation or the machine itself.

I've tried wiping R and Shiny server in order to figure it out but it always ends the same way. The message itself doesn't lead me anywhere due to the packages not being able to track down and log file removing itself.

```
Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'i18n-1.2.0'; `directoryPath` = '',
[2022-01-17T16:48:47.246] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.,
```

I use Shiny Server as a service and also, currently, [in a docker container](https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny).But the output is the same, I even went as far as deleting the OS and reinstalling everything. The only packages that I use besides from Shiny and Rmarkdown are:

- learnr
- ggplot2
- readxl
- httr
- Hmisc (not all of them include this but I use them too)

Any help will be highly appreciated as I'm running down the path of insanity with this bug.

Edit:

.RMD that crashes on this machine:
https://pastebin.com/q2XRRS4D

Comment: I don't know that we can help here without a reproducible question, including (namely) a simple Rmarkdown document in shiny that triggers the error.

Comment: @r2evans https://pastebin.com/q2XRRS4D

Comment: Thanks, but that is neither [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) nor is it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). You don't tell us *where* in the code this error happens, and since we don't have sample data (three csv files, on a casual read) you are asking us to take on-faith how the data might be structured.

Comment: It would be *far* better to provide only data required (preferably a small frame, don't need everything) and only code required (no filler, no unrelated blocks) to reproduce the issue.